# Blackholes, endothermic?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes

I am currently learning about endothermic and exothermic processes and I came to think about black holes. Are they endothermic or exothermic?

If they are endothermic then why? Is it because they "consume" energy from stars and accretion discs? Or are they exothermic if one considers Hawking Radiation and maybe other factors? Excuse me if my question sounds absurd, I am no expert in such fields.

Comment: A black hole isn't a process so it's hard to see how the adjectives *endothermic* or *exothermic* could be applied to it.

Comment: @John Rennie Right but I am thinking about the reactions within it. Or rather about the energy taken inside the black hole where, one can say, it will be accumulated. The processes when energy get "sucked" into the black hole.

Comment: Related questions [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64619](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64619) and [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194347](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194347)